# Sequence of $X_i$ are greater than their Expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$,$X_2$ be an i.i.d. sequence of RV's with CDF $F(x)$. Let $Y(x)=\min(i:X_i > x)$. Find $P(Y(x)> E[Y(x)])$. (F<1 everywhere) What is the limit as $x$ goes to infinity?

Here's the work I have so far:

$P(Y(x)=i) = P(X_1<x)P(X_2<x)\dots P(X_{i+1}>x) = F(x)^i(1-F(x))$

$E[Y(x)] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}iF(x)^i(1-F(x))$

The sum is almost geometric, but I'm having trouble dealing with it. If I do the sum one way I get: $\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}$ but if I do it another I get $\frac{1}{1-F(x)}$. Thoughts on how to complete?

Comment: Your equation for $Y(x)$ makes no sense. On the left you have a random variable and on the right you have a probability. I think what you meant on the left-hand side of that equation is $P(Y(x)=i+1)$? (That raises the question why you wrote it for $i+1$ and not for $i$, and shows that the expectation in the following equation is wrong, since you're using this as if it were $P(Y(x)=i)$. Once you've corrected it, pull $1-F$ out of the sum, and then consider what would happen if you wrote $q$ for $F(x)$ inside the sum and integrated with respect to $q$.

Comment: Also, since you've already made two attempts to find the sum, you should present them here -- how can we tell you what's wrong with them when you don't write them down?

Comment: What @joriki explained. (About the question itself, rather amusingly, the limit seems to be $1/e$ provided $F<1$ everywhere. The exponential case might be worth a deeper look... Note that if $F(x)=1$ for some finite $x$, the question makes no sense, hence the hypothesis that $F<1$ everywhere should be added to the question.)

Comment: o sweet I didn't know it was somewhere else!! Excellent.